# How to simplify my jquery IF statement on multiple options

Tags: jquery

```
<select>
  <option value="2">option 1</option>
  <option value="5">option 2</option>
  <option value="6">option 3</option>
  <option value="9">option 4</option>
  <option value="20">option 5</option>
  <option value="21">option 6</option>
  <option value="22">option 7</option>
  <option value="80">option 8</option>
  <option value="91">option 9</option>
  <option value="145">option 10</option>
  <option value="66">option 11</option>
  <option value="70">option 12</option>
  <option value="99">option 13</option>
</select>
```

I have a long select list which longer than above, I wonder how to simplify my following jquery statement as the options I would like to target individually is pretty long and redundant.

```
      $('select option').each(function(){

        $option =  $(this).val();           


        if (($option == 5 || $option == 9 || $option == 22 || $option = 80 .....)){           
           $(this).addClass('myclass');
        };

     });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$.inArray()`

```
var ar = [5,9,22,80];
if(jQuery.inArray($option ,ar ) != -1){
    $(this).addClass('myclass');
};
```

You can also narrow down the selector and directly addClass using:

```
$("select option[value='" + ar.join("'],[value='") + "']").addClass("myclass");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2srzcze6/)**

Comment: I'm really confused with second method ar.join("'],[.... can you explain please...

Comment: @C-linkNepal: that's separator parameter. see the docs http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp.

Comment: Great! I wonder how to reverse instead. That's mean anything that is NOT in the ar = [....] ?

Comment: @Adamtan: by using condition `if(jQuery.inArray($option ,ar ) == -1)` in first example.You will also need to parse option values to int or rather use string array. here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/x0jarwfs/